# Swift | RoomBuilder's RoomCaptureView export USDZ with blocks instead furniture

Tags: swift, swiftui, scnscene, sceneview, roomplan

I am looking for the property or option to disable the furniture items displayed in the usdz after a room is scanned via RoomCaptureView (replacing furniture items with solid blocks/blobs). I have done this in the past(I think), but I cannot seem to figure it out now to save my life and I am not coming up with a solution via google as well, so here I am. I do not think code is required to get to bottom of this  "problem"  but will share just in case:

RoomCapture Controller code:

```
import Foundation
import RoomPlan

class RoomCaptureController: ObservableObject, RoomCaptureViewDelegate, RoomCaptureSessionDelegate {
    private let roomBuilder = RoomBuilder(options: [.beautifyObjects])
    
    @Published var roomCaptureView: RoomCaptureView
    @Published var finalResult: CapturedRoom?

    var sessionConfig: RoomCaptureSession.Configuration

    init() {
        roomCaptureView = RoomCaptureView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 42, height: 42))
        sessionConfig = RoomCaptureSession.Configuration()
        roomCaptureView.captureSession.delegate = self
        roomCaptureView.delegate = self
    }
    
    func startSession() {
        roomCaptureView.captureSession.run(configuration: sessionConfig)
    }

    func stopSession() {
        roomCaptureView.captureSession.stop()
    }

    func captureView(shouldPresent roomDataForProcessing: CapturedRoomData, error: Error?) -> Bool {
        print("called captureView(shouldPresent")
        // Return false because we want to present our own processed view.
        return false
    }
    
    func captureSession(_ session: RoomCaptureSession, didEndWith data: CapturedRoomData, error: (Error)?) {
        print("called captureSession(didEndWith)")
        do {
            finalResult = try await roomBuilder.capturedRoom(from: data)
            saveAndViewCapturedRoom()
        } catch {
            // Handle the error
            print("Error processing captured room: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
    }

    func captureView(didPresent processedResult: CapturedRoom, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
                print("Error in captureView: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        finalResult = processedResult
    }
    
    func saveAndViewCapturedRoom() {
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let exportedRoomsDirectory = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(Constants.exportedRoomsDirectory)
        let usdzURL = exportedRoomsDirectory
            .appendingPathComponent("test.usdz")
        let metadataURL = exportedRoomsDirectory
            .appendingPathComponent("test.plist")
        // Load the catalog 3D models
        do {
            let modelProvider: CapturedRoom.ModelProvider? = try CapturedRoom.ModelProvider.load()
            // Export the captured room with the 3D models
            guard let result = finalResult else {
                print("finalResult is nil. Cannot export.")
                return
            }
            do {
                try result.export(
                    to: usdzURL,
                    metadataURL: metadataURL,
                    modelProvider: modelProvider,
                    exportOptions: .model)
                print("Export successful to \(usdzURL.path)")
            } catch {
                print("Error during export: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

        } catch {
            print("Error saving and viewing usdz scan: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Not needed.")
    }

    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Not needed.")
     }
}
```

Displaying .usdz file in a SceneView after loading it in SCNScene. Code:

Creating SCNScene:

```
class SomeClass {
    var scene: SCNScene?
    
    func loadScene(_ exportedusdzURL: URL) {
        scene = State(initialValue: try SCNScene(url: exportedusdzURL, options: []))
    }
    
    func getSceneView() -> SceneView {
        if let scene = scene {
            return SceneView(
                scene: scene,
                options: [.allowsCameraControl, .autoenablesDefaultLighting]
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Apologies if there is a complier or like error in the code, I have pieced it together from various places in order to show only relevent code to the question.

Comment: I believe what I am looking for is not possible via a single property etc. This possible by replacing the node I want to replace with a usdz model of my own in SceneView.
But for now, what I ended up doing is just hiding the furniture nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the default cuboids for objects don't use a `CapturedRoom.ModelProvider` on export. That is, there's no need for the line:

```
let modelProvider: CapturedRoom.ModelProvider? = try CapturedRoom.ModelProvider.load()
```

And line:

```
try result.export(to: usdzURL,
                    metadataURL: metadataURL,
                    modelProvider: modelProvider,
                    exportOptions: .model)
```

can be:

```
try result.export(to: usdzURL,
                    metadataURL: metadataURL)
```

If you want to use custom models for objects on export you should watch the [Explore enhancements to RoomPlan](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10192/) WWDC 2023 session for how to configure your `ModelProvider` to vend custom models on export.